# is there a way to get source code with macro expanded using Clang API

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

For example, I got following code.

```
#define ADD(x, y) (x) + (y) 

int func(int i, int j) 
{ 
   return ADD(i, j); 
}
```

The clang SourceManager can be used to get source code of the function func. and what I got is `{ return ADD(i, j)`. is there any way that I can get the source code as `{ return (i) + (j); }` ?

Answer from keyboardsmoke: tested

Can simply use Decl::print() method, or keyboardsmoke's code in this answer, actually, Decl::print() calls methods of DeclPrinter.

Stmt has a different method called printPretty() that can print out the source code of a statement with macro expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use the 'print' function inside of Decl, the pretty printer will expand all macros.

You can also print statements, so if you want that specific statement that is being returned you should be able to do something similar.

Decl::print also refers to "DeclPrinter" which allows you to print any decl type (output to raw_ostream)

```
std::string s;
llvm::raw_string_ostream sos(s);
PrintingPolicy pp(compiler->getLangOpts());
pp.adjustForCPlusPlus();
DeclPrinter DP(sos, pp, 0 /* indent */, true /* PrintInstantiation */);
DP.Visit(functionDecl);
```

Will place the text for "functionDecl" into "std::string s"

Comment: I don't see a `print` in FunctionDecl: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl-members.html   I see printName (and variations), but presumably that doesn't do what you describe.

Comment: my mistake, for most declarations the previous advice of using "print" method will work, the "Decl" class has "print", so try using "clang::cast<clang::Decl>(functionDecl)->print". I will make the answer better, because there also exists "DeclPrinter" which achieves the same effect for all decls

Comment: -actually you were probably right.   There is a bug in the doxygen docs that don't pick up things in Decl.   It's an open bug with clang but they think it's an issue with doxygen, I think.   Anyhow, there's no need to cast to a base type.   It will just work.  Relevant docs are here: http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Decl.html

Comment: Well let me know if it works out so I can correct my answer if necessary

Comment: yes, you are right, Decl::print() works, but one strange thing is that it works perfect for FunctionDecl. but not for VarDecl. if I have a global var defined as const char * g_string  = “123456”, Decl::print() gives const char * g_string = ",

Comment: You didn't ask about vardecl in the original comment, and your last comment was cut short. What is the issue?

Comment: Keep in mind that PrintInstantiation value might need to change across declaration types too, it'll output too little or too much information from time to time.